# android studio can read one of my assets files, but not others

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to read from a .txt file in my assets folder in android studio, and i was able to get it working with one of my files, but when I added the others and tried to read from them, i get a "java.io.FileNotFoundException"

for example

```
    val inputStream: BufferedReader = requireActivity().assets.open("example1.txt").bufferedReader()
        val lineList = mutableListOf<String>()
```

will work, but

```
    val inputStream: BufferedReader = requireActivity().assets.open("example2.txt").bufferedReader()
 val lineList = mutableListOf<String>()
```

wont, despite being in the same location with the same code

Comment: The file is not there. Look again please.

Comment: can you please provide a screenshot of the assets folder ?